# Linux terminal- Converting numerous bytes of hex into ASCII from a text file

Tags: linux, hex, ascii

I have 8 bytes of hex on each line of a text file. Is it possible to convert this into ASCII? For example, `215f6674` should convert to `!_ft`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming exactly eight hexadecimals per line, here is a pure `bash` solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read a
do
   # echo $a
   printf "\x${a:0:2}\x${a:2:2}\x${a:4:2}\x${a:6:2}\n"
done < infile
```

If `infile` contains:

```
215f6674
41424344
61626364
```

the output from this script is:

```
!_ft
ABCD
abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify any constraints on your environment, so, I chose to solve this with a simple perl command line

```
perl -pe 's/([a-fA-F0-9][[a-fA-F0-9])/chr(hex($1))/eg' < your_file_of_hex
```

By way of explanation, the regular expression grabs two hex characters at a time and applies two functions. The first, 'hex', converts those two hex charters to a int. The second, 'chr', converts that int into its ascii equivalent.

For example

```
>> cat hex
414243
215f6674
616263

>> perl -pe 's/([a-fA-F0-9][[a-fA-F0-9])/chr(hex($1))/eg'<hex
ABC
!_ft
abc
>>
```

Comment: Note that this is a quick and dirty command line script. If this were meant to be production code, I'd check each line to ascertain it contained only legal hex pairs. Further one would want to consider how to handle non-printable values.